# Why doesn't Proguard appear to obfuscate code?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console, android-vitals

I'm using kotlin for Android, it works, and I upload the mapping.txt to Android Vitals, but the stack trace in Android Vitals is not correct at all. Does any one know why?

[image]